# EmojiAppCompatEditText doesn't show spaces

Tags: android, android-appcompat, emoji

I've replaced one `EditText` in my application with `EmojiAppCompatEditText` and emojis works perfect, but when I type digits they appear with little spaces and plain spaces doesn't appear at all. When I press send and text from field appears in `EmojiAppCompatTextView` everything is fine.

Here is my xml:

```
    <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiAppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/message_box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/attach_btn"
            android:fontFamily="@font/noto_color_emoji_compat"
            android:hint="@string/say_something"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textShortMessage|textCapSentences"
            android:maxHeight="200dp" />
```

Code in `onCreate()` of Application class (that's copy-paste from examples):

```
        val fontRequest = FontRequest(
                "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
                "com.google.android.gms",
                "Noto Color Emoji Compat",
                R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs)
        val config = FontRequestEmojiCompatConfig(applicationContext, fontRequest)
            .setReplaceAll(true)
            .setEmojiSpanIndicatorEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        EmojiCompat.init(config)
```

And generated by AndroidStudio file `noto_color_emoji_compat.xml` from `font` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:fontProviderAuthority="com.google.android.gms.fonts"
        app:fontProviderPackage="com.google.android.gms"
        app:fontProviderQuery="Noto Color Emoji Compat"
        app:fontProviderCerts="@array/com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs">
</font-family>
```

Issue reproduced on Android 6.0 and 7.0. AppCompat libraries version is 26.0.2

Also, I've filled [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65658544)

Screenshot of `EmojiAppCompatEditText` and `EmojiAppCompatTextView` with same string.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmojiAppCompatEditText` automatically uses the emoji font configured via `EmojiCompat.init()` for Emoji characters.
But by referencing the EmojiCompat font via the `android:fontFamily` attribute you're telling the `EditText` to always use the emoji font, i.e. also for non-emoji characters. The emoji font contains glyphs for digits which is why the number is rendered weird. It also contains a glyph for the space character, but it has zero width. That explains why you're seeing no spaces. For all glyphs that aren't present in the emoji font the fallback font is used. That's why "G" and "g" look okay.

The solution is to simply remove the `android:fontFamily` attribute from `EmojiAppCompatEditText`. It will still do its magic for emoji characters and render all non-emoji characters using the font from the theme.